# What will happen with tables SQLite, If application be re-installed or deleted?

Tags: android, sqlite

The tables are filled, when application working.

What will happen with tables SQLite, If application be re-installed or deleted?

Will it be deleted or saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you delete an application, all its SQLite tables will be deleted. However, there is a possibility to backup your tables: [Data Backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)